# Find and drop a field containing a specific string

Tags: mongodb

In myCollection I want to find all fields containing the string "Hello" and remove their values or remove the fields it doesn't matter. For example:

```
{"_id" : "1", "name" : "pingo", "ref" : "HelloWorldFine", "comment" : "specifications must be defined" }
{"_id" : "2", "name" : "Paolo.hello:ttt", "ref" : "3984", "comment" : "ello" }
```

So drop "ref" or its value in doc _id:1 and drop "name" or its value in doc _id:2. I don't know where to start, use $unset or db.coll.remove() and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$unset`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/#up._S_unset) is the operator to use for that, and you'd need to do it one field at a time.

```js
db.test.update({ref: /hello/i}, {$unset: {ref: 1}}, {multi: true})
db.test.update({name: /hello/i}, {$unset: {name: 1}}, {multi: true})
```

`/hello/i` is a regular expression that does a case insensitive search for "hello".

Comment: Thank you, and how to do if I want to do the same thing to a sub document "firstName" of the field "name"?

Comment: @user3665192 Just use dot notation in the field names for that: `db.test.update({'name.firstName': /hello/i}, {$unset: {'name.firstName': 1}})`

Comment: @user3665192 Thanks for the edit to add `multi`; good catch as it's needed here.